# Horizontal Pop up Menu?

Tags: android, grid, popupmenu, horizontallist

I am trying to make share button when clicked a `Popupmenu` appears with three horizontal choices `facebook`, `twitter` and `google+`.

I keep searching for a while but I got nothing until now.

Is it possible to create horizontal or even grid `PopupMenu`?
Is it possible to use `RecyclerView` in `PopupMenu`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `PopupMenu`, would you be able to use a `DialogFragment` with a custom layout?

Comment: A `PopupMenu` is designed to anchor a floating view (typically for selecting items) to a specific point in the current view, while a `DialogFragment` is meant to be a freestanding dialog view with its own context and root. You would be exponentially increasing the steps to take a vertical layout and make it horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use `PopupWindow`. You can use `ListView` to display items in each line. Example code to show a `PopupWindow`:

```
 public PopupWindow popupWindowsort() {

    // initialize a pop up window type
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);

    ArrayList<String> sortList = new ArrayList<String>();
    sortList.add("Google+");
    sortList.add("Facebook");
    sortList.add("Twitter");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, sortList);
    // the drop down list is a list view
    ListView listViewSort = new ListView(this);

    // set our adapter and pass our pop up window contents
    listViewSort.setAdapter(adapter);

    // set on item selected
    listViewSort.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener());

    // some other visual settings for popup window
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setWidth(250);
    //popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white));
    popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // set the list view as pop up window content
    popupWindow.setContentView(listViewSort);

    return popupWindow;
}
```

Visit my post for more details: http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/02/android-popupwindow-show-as-dropdown.html. 
Hope this help!

Comment: You still need to address the `horizontal` portion of a `horizontal list`

Answer (score 0):

Create a basic layout XML with an inner horizontal layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/popup_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Assign the layout to the PopupMenu, then use the inner layout.

```
// PopupMenu accepts ViewGroup, so cast the inflated layout view
// Replace ROOT_VIEW_HERE with the parent view of the PopupMenu
LinearLayout popupWindow = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.popup_window, ROOT_VIEW_HERE);
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, popupWindow);
LinearLayout innerView = popupWindow.findViewById(R.id.popup_horizontal);
```

It really is that simple.

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution is:

1 - The Custom PopupMenu class:

```
public class PopupMenuCustomLayout {
    private PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener onClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private PopupWindow popupWindow;
    private int rLayoutId;
    private View popupView;

    public PopupMenuCustomLayout(Context context, int rLayoutId, PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        this.rLayoutId = rLayoutId;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        popupView = inflater.inflate(rLayoutId, null);
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = true;
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);
        popupWindow.setElevation(10);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) popupView;
        for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            v.setOnClickListener( v1 -> { onClickListener.onClick( v1.getId()); popupWindow.dismiss(); });
        }
    }
    public void setAnimationStyle( int animationStyle) {
        popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(animationStyle);
    }
    public void show() {
        popupWindow.showAtLocation( popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }

    public void show( View anchorView, int gravity, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown( anchorView, 0, -2 * (anchorView.getHeight()));
    }

    public interface PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener {
        public void onClick(int menuItemId);
    }
}
```

2 - Your custom layout, e.g. linearlayout with horizontal layout. In this case I use a simple LinearLayout with TextView items. You can use Buttons, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_custom_item_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_custom_item_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="B"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    // ...
</LinearLayout>
```

3 - Using the Custom PopupMenu like the normal PopupMenu.

```
PopupMenuCustomLayout popupMenu = new PopupMenuCustomLayout(
        MainActivity.mainActivity, R.layout.popup_menu_custom_layout,
        new PopupMenuCustomLayout.PopupMenuCustomOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int itemId) {
                // log statement: "Clicked on: " + itemId
                switch (itemId) {
                    case R.id.popup_menu_custom_item_a:
                        // log statement: "Item A was clicked!"
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
// Method 1: popupMenu.show();
// Method 2: via an anchor view: 
popupMenu.show( anchorView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit excessive to switch orientations, though?